# BlackBerry - Resource files for Brazilian Portuguese

Tags: blackberry, localization

I want a resource file for Brazilian Portuguese.

I have created .RRC files for various languages - basic localisation is not the problem.

- `MyApp_pt.rrc` *works* when phone is set to Portuguese.
- `MyApp_pt_BR.rrc` *does not work* when phone is set to Brazilian Portuguese (even though the firmware UI updates to that language)

### Question:

What localisation suffix should I use for Brazilian Portuguese?

---

### Update:

The actual issue seems to have been certain string keys in the .rrc file that broke the build. I have seen this issue before, and should have checked for it.

Comment: I've used pt_BR successfully.  Does your build process include that file correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use pt_BR. No reason it shouldn't work.